# How does work method GetFormat

Tags: .net

Please describe me how does work method GetFormat. Below I have given a typical example of the method. I don't undersand what object we put in "formatType", when we call string.Format and why we return "this"?

Thanks for your answers.

```
 class TimeWordFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
 {
    static readonly string[] hours = { "h", "hours", "H" };
    static readonly string[] minutes = { "m", "minutes", "M" };
    static readonly string[] seconds = { "s", "seconds", "S" };

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        {
            return this;
        }

        else 
        {
         return null;

        }
    }


    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (arg == null || !(arg is TimeSpan) || format != "W")
            return string.Format("{0:" + format + "}", arg);

        TimeSpan time = (TimeSpan)arg;

        string hh = GetCase(time.Hours, hours);
        string mm = GetCase(time.Minutes, minutes);
        string ss = GetCase(time.Seconds, seconds);

        return string.Format("{0:%h} {1} {0:%m} {2} {0:%s} {3}", time, hh, mm, ss);
    }

    static string GetCase(int value, string[] options)
    {
        value = Math.Abs(value) % 100;

        if (value > 10 && value < 15)
            return options[2];

        value %= 10;
        if (value == 1) return options[0];
        if (value > 1 && value < 5) return options[1];
        return options[2];
    }

     static void Main()
    {

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        string formattedTime = string.Format(new TimeWordFormatter(), "{0:W}", now.TimeOfDay);
        Console.WriteLine(formattedTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.getformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I read this example, but didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

`I don't undersand what object we put in "formatType"` Look at the method signature. `formatType` is a `Type`. You pass it a `Type`. It's defined in [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.getformat(v=vs.110).aspx) and as such, you probably don't need to call it yourself. There will be some other method that is expecting an `IFormatProvider` so it can call `GetFormat`.

As for returning `this`. `IFormatProvider` has a single method `GetFormat` that returns an object of whatever `Type` was passed to `GetFormat`. In this case, the object that does that is the same `TimeWordFormatter` that implements `GetFormat` (since it also implements `ICustomFormatter`). So it just returns the current instance with the C# keyword `this`.

Comment: What object I put to "formatType" in my example? Where I get it?

Why we return current instance? I don't understant why we should use GetFormat in this example.

Comment: @Makeda: YOU don't use `GetFormat`. `string.Format` will call `GetFormat` and ask for an `ICustomFormatter`. Your `TimeWordFormatter` will return itself because it is an `ICustomFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here as I was pulling my hair out, trying to understand based on microsoft's documentation, with what value(s), when and how many times my `GetFormat(Type formatType)` method will be called if I want to use it in a`string.Format` call. Is it being called only once per `string.Format` call, or is it maybe being called for each argument I supplied for my string pattern? What other type(s) (other than `ICustomFormatter`) is it (possibly) being invoked with, and why do we have to return `null` then? How the heck does this actually work? It would be nice to understand the big picture. But nope, it's nowhere documented!
Instead we have very "helpful" documentation, such as

> Its IFormatProvider.GetFormat method determines whether the formatType
> parameter represents an ICustomFormatter type. If it does,
> BinaryFormatter returns an instance of itself; otherwise, it returns
> null.

above the code sample. Thank you Microsoft, this is fantastic to know!

I ended up doing an experiment with a dummy `IFormatProvider` implementation:

```
        class Test : IFormatProvider
        {
            public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And called it like:

```
    string.Format(new Test(), pattern, arguments);
```

where `arguments` was an array containing 2 strings in my case, and `pattern` a string having 2 placeholders, respectively.

Here's the call stack:

> Test.GetFormat(System.Type formatType) Line 34  C#
> mscorlib.dll!System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, System.ParamsArray args)  Unknown
> mscorlib.dll!string.FormatHelper(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, System.ParamsArray args)   Unknown
> mscorlib.dll!string.Format(System.IFormatProvider provider, string format, object[] args)   Unknown

**So, `System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper` is the method where the answer lies to all our questions.** Check this out: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,2c3b4c2e7c43f5a4,references

As it turns out, `GetFormat` is called only once, and is never called with any other type except for `typeof(ICustomFormatter)`. Returning null in case of other type parameter is probably just necessary for future compliance!